# Truffle migrations - UNABLE TO MIGRATE (Error: Deployment Failed)

Tags: truffle, blockchain, truffle-migration, rinkeby

The compilations goes well on the Rinkeby testnet using the command

```
geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi="personal,eth,network,web3,net" --ipcpath "~/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc" --syncmode light --cache 64 --maxpeers 32
```

but after that when the migration starts, it exits giving the error:

[image]

**The geth console gives this:**

[image]

Truffle Configuration goes like this:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },
    rinkeby: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,             //port for GETH
      network_id: 4,        //network ID of Rinkeby TestNet
      gas: 7000000 
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this issue: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/19424.

Because you were sending LES/1 version of transaction through LES/2 protocol.

I think the only way to fix this is upgrade the geth.